Warning: move_uploaded_file
Buen día.
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en PHP MySQL y JS, donde tengo que subir un archivo, y guardar los datos y la url del archivo en la base de datos.
Al ingresar el registro se guarda bien en la tabla, no sube el archivo al directorio correspondiente /Assets/archivos/.
En red sale el siguiente error:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/Assets/archivos/view-documentos.png): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/doctos2/Controllers/Documentos.php on line 94


Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "/tmp/php47VCCw" to "/Assets/archivos/view-documentos.png" in /var/www/html/doctos2/Controllers/Documentos.php on line 94
{"msg":"Documento registrado con éxito","icono":"success"}

if ($data == "ok") {
   $msg = array('msg' => 'Documento registrado con éxito', 'icono' => 'success');
   move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $destino);


El directorio archivos tiene permisos 777
Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar para solucionar este inconveniente, estaré muy agradecido.
Un Saludo desde Valparaíso - Chile

Ya has logrado averiguar si es tema de permisos o es algo de programación? Te recomiendo, en el root del sitio, sube archivos de prueba con esta respuesta y si funciona, no es tema permisos

¿Estás seguro de que la ruta completa al directorio Assets es esa? Por lo general uno tiende a ubicar esos directorios dentro del mismo proyecto y no en la raíz del sistema operativo.

quitale el primer / a /Assets/archivos/ para que la ruta sea relativa al php. si es unas carpetas arriba vas a tener que calcularle el root path. la ruta final interpretada por el OS será algo como /var/www/html/doctos2/Assets/archivos/ los permisos de archivo conviene no ser muy relajado, proba 2775 para que herede el owner y sea accesible por el grupo

Gracias a todos por sus aportes, la solución fue la de @alo Malbarez
habia que qitar el / del principio, Muchas Gracias

Ahora siguiendo con el mismo sistema, como puedo hacerlo para que se pueda subir cualquier tipo de archivo, por ejemplo, PDF, PNG Y XLS, pero que en la vista muestre icono segun el tipo de archivo, se puede, algún tutorial o ejemplo, o tengo que poner mi código completo para que me ayuden.
